# jquery mobile <a> data-role button disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an image that serves as a button. This is the code:

```
<a href="#frmqt" onClick="s()"><img src="images/buttons/BEGINNER.png"/></a>
```

And what I'm trying to do is when I clicked this image, the button(which is coded as:

`<a href="#area" onClick="beginIt()" name="start" data-role="button" data-theme="l">START</a>` ) would be disabled and not functional.

Is it possible to the `<a>` tag with data role button would be disabled and functional using javascript?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the button add the class `ui-disabled`.

Ref: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

Side note, if you can try to avoid mixing of inline and jQuery function/handler.

Code:

```
function s() {
    $("a[name*='start']").addClass('ui-disabled');
}

function beginIt() {alert('demo');}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/qnFnM/

### EDIT

To reenable the element you can use:

```
$("a[name*='start']").removeClass('ui-disabled');
```

if you plan to use your button as toggle for the element use:

```
$("a[name*='start']").toggleClass('ui-disabled');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qnFnM/1/

Comment: Glad to help you, if solved consider to upvote/mark as accepted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: this worked fine. Thank you very much. But I have question here. Is this code functional to enable it again? `$("a[name*='start']").addClass('ui-enable');`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily.

First, jQuery Mobile have methods to disable the button but they don't work on a **<a>** tag button, only on a **<input>** and **<button>** tag buttons.

Method can be found in an official documentation **[here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/)**, or to be more precise here a method **[disable](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable)**.

To disable basic **<a>** tag button you need to do 2 steps, one step is to change it looks to disabled state and other one is to disable click and other events placed on it.

It can be done like this:

```
$('.button-example').prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-disabled');
```

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YFMsR/

And if you want to find out more take a look at my blog **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/enable-disable-jquery-mobile-button/)** related to this topic.